# Add background image to font awesome icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm wanting to add an image in a font awesome icon.  Say I have the icon-star-empty and want to fill the internal part of that start with a photo.  Is that possible?  I have hacked at it, but gotten anywhere really.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
[class^="icon-"]::before,
[class*=" icon-"]::before {
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: inherit;
}
.icon-star-empty:before {
content: "\f006";
}

.iconBackground:before {
font-size: 72px;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f00), to(#333));
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
display initial;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kZeSZ/3/

Added a fiddle per request below.

Comment: You should detail a little more your case, specifying what you've tried and so on. By the way, have you tried to force `background-image` in the `i` element? Try to make a jsFiddle to let us play with your idea on the fly.

Comment: Are you interested in a WebKit only solution?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge No I didn't think of that. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @thirtydot  I'm interested in any working solution at this point. :)

Comment: Here is a fiddle if you want to play with it:  http://jsfiddle.net/kZeSZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea I had which only works in WebKit relies on `-webkit-background-clip: text`.

It also relies on there also being a solid version of the shape in question, in this case there is [`.icon-star`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/star/) to accompany [`.icon-star-empty`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/star-empty/).

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/mPA8N/2/

[image]

```css
.icon-star-empty-filled {
    font-size: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.icon-star-empty-filled:before {
    content: "\f005";
    color: transparent;
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
.icon-star-empty-filled:after {
    content: "\f006";
    color: transparent;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f00), to(#333));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you need to support other browsers, use SVG to do this instead.